# How can I understand `Nodes` in EKS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I deployed a EKS cluster and a fargate profile. Then I deployed a few application to this cluster. I can see these fargate instances are launched.

[image]

when I click each of this instance, it shows me some information like `os`, `image` etc. But it doesn't tell me the CPU and memory. When I look at fargate pricing: https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/. It is calculated based on CPU and Memory.

I have used ECS and it is very clear that I need to provision CPU/Memory in service/task level. But I can't find anything in EKS.

How do I know how much resources they are consuming?

Comment: When you use Fargate with EKS, resources are provisioned based on pod's requests and limits. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-pod-configuration.html

Comment: @VASャ is correct. With ECS you pick the task size upfront. The way we do this in Kubernetes is by checking the `requests` in each container of a given pod and we calculate the pod size off of that (see the rule we use in the link VAS provided).

Comment: One other thing I would add is, don't look at the node size (e.g. by describing the nodes via kubectl). They are unrelated to the actual size of the environment we configured (and that you are paying for). Check the size of the environment via the `CapacityProvisioned` annotation in the pod.

Answer (score 1):

With Fargate you don`t have provision, configure or scale virtual machines to run your containers so that they become fundamental compute primitive.

This solution model is called `serverless` where you are being charged for only the compute resources and storage that are need to execute some piece of your code. It does not mean that there are not server involved in this, it just you don`t need to care about those.

To monitor there those you can use [CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/viewing_cloudwatch_metrics.html#viewing_service_metrics).  Below documents describe how this can be achieved:

- [How do I troubleshoot high CPU utilization on an Amazon ECS task on
  Fargate?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-high-cpu-utilization/)
- [How can I monitor high memory utilization for Amazon ECS tasks on

  Fargate?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-tasks-fargate-memory-utilization/)

It is worth to mention that Fargate is just a launch type for ECS (Another one is EC2). Please have a look at the [diagram](https://epsagon.com/development/key-metrics-for-monitoring-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate/) in this document for clear image of how those are connected. The CloudWatch metrics are collected automatically for Fargate. If you are using the AKS with Fargate you can monitor them with usage of metrics-addon or prometheus inside your kubernetes cluster.

Here's an [example](https://sysdig.com/blog/monitor-aws-fargate-prometheus/) of monitoring Fargate with Prometheus. Notice that it scrapes the metrics from CloudWatch.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think you mentioned about how to check it in ECS which I understand it. But my question is how to do that in EKS.

Comment: Please check below https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/monitoring-fargate-usage.html